# How to connect travis ci mongodb service from inside docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, travis-ci

See the logs of: https://travis-ci.com/Jeff-Tian/uni-sso/builds/147317611

I created a travis CI project, that uses `mongodb` service. And it then runs a docker which from inside will connect that mongodb. But as the log shows, it will fail.

I tried those MONGO_URI, none of them works:

- mongodb://localhost:27017
- mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
- mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017

Can anyone shed some light on this? I can't find a solution either from Travis CI document nor google.

Thanks in advance!

**more details**
I can use `mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017` in travis ci unit test, but inside the docker it would fail.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @zoranjeremic, no I haven't solve this issue, rather I worked around it. I use 3rd party mongodb and configured that 3rd party mongo db's public URL for the docker to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably already late for you, but I've managed to find solution for the same problem I had here https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/.
This approach binds docker container directly to the Docker host’s network

My script to run tests in docker container:

```
script:
   - docker run --network host -e CI=true mydocker/api-test npm test
```

Then, from your test you can access mongodb using this url
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongo_db_name

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, it is very helpful and not late. And inspired me to use it not only in the travis ci but also in my local env.  :-)